# Как превратить string representation numpy.array в обычный List?

Tags: python, строки, list, numpy

У меня есть `numpy.ndarray`:

```
array(['[10.321302  8.602723]', '[-9.538208   7.8033323]',
       '[4.393315  0.2483275]', '[9.066099 9.88853 ]',
       '[-14.339188 -12.510495]'], dtype=object)
```

Я хочу его превратить в обычный список.
Должно быть вот так:

```
[[10.321302,  8.602723], [-9.538208,   7.8033323],
       [4.393315,  0.2483275], [9.066099, 9.88853],
       [-14.339188, -12.510495]]
```

Т. е. я хочу убрать скобки и преобразовать `numpy.ndarray` в `list`.
Пробовал использовать `ast.literal_eval`, но не работает.

Как сделать это преобразование?

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['[10.321302  8.602723]', '[-9.538208   7.8033323]',
       '[4.393315  0.2483275]', '[9.066099 9.88853 ]',
       '[-14.339188 -12.510495]'])

res = [np.safe_eval(",".join(x.split())) for x in arr]
```

res:

```
[[10.321302, 8.602723],
 [-9.538208, 7.8033323],
 [4.393315, 0.2483275],
 [9.066099, 9.88853],
 [-14.339188, -12.510495]]
```